# How to set automatic night mode in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, night-light

How to set automatic night mode in Ubuntu 20.04?

In Ubuntu 19.04 options I have
to set the time automatic night mode on.

Comment: i think it changed to displays in the settings for 20.04

Comment: ok i searching not find you find tell me

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6mHP.png

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, the settings for night mode are available under the "Display" tab in "Settings". Once there, you will see a button "Night Light" in the top bar that brings you to the dialog you are looking for.

Comment: In Lubuntu (LXQT), you have "dark" in preferences -> lxqt settings -> appearance. In Lxqt Theme, the default is `Lubuntu Arc`. 'Dark' sets the Menu in the bottom left and the task bar to black background, white font. Can I change all programms such as chromium to this color scheme, not just the menu?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your Settings>Privacy>Location Services> [On]

otherwise, the automated setting for night light won't work.

Comment: For me it works exactly as scheduled, while the location service you mention is firmly disabled. It does not depend on it.