# Night mode has disappeared from Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

Strangely, today the night mode seems to have suddenly gone. It is still there in the settings, and I haven't changed those, but the functionality has gone. There used to be a little icon on the right in that small top bar, this too isn't there any more. This is so no matter whether location services are turned on or off.

Does anyone else have similar experience and, more importantly, is there a solution?

This question, [How to set automatic night mode in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251418/how-to-set-automatic-night-mode-in-ubuntu-20-04), is already older, so doesn't address the problem.

Comment: Did you use a [Gnome extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/) for this functionality? You might want to go through any extensions you have installed. Maybe one of them has been disabled for some reason, maybe an update has gone wrong, maybe the extension in question doesn't support your version of Gnome anymore.

Comment: I have seen more comments here, now I can't see them any more. I am trying to answer the question about display settings as I remember it. Yes, I can find the night light settings under "display". Night light is enabled, but the little night light icon that used to be in the very top bar of the screen window is not there. Last night when I shut my computer down it was still there, this morning when I turn it on again it isn't; and the same with the functionality.

Comment: I am not aware of any recent changes to my system, and to my knowledge I don't use any Gnome extensions.

Comment: But well, something must have changed. Maybe I can find it … At least there is hope, as other users still have the night light function.

Comment: At least I found a workaround: Setting the time for the night mode 00:00–23:59 instead of 00:00–00:00 as it had been before makes it work again (after reboot). I am glad! Even during daytime, it is considerably less stressful to my eyes.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, as questions with answers in the comments can't have their answers marked as the accepted answer. BTW (w.r.t. your note "This thread..."), Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a forum of threaded messages.

Comment: > w.r.t. your note "This thread..."), Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a forum of threaded messages. – Greenonline

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am new to the forum, and am not a native English speaker, so sometimes am not sure about the correct expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found a workaround: Setting the time for the night mode 00:00–23:59 instead of 00:00–00:00 as it had been before makes it work again (after reboot). I am glad! Even during daytime, it is considerably less stressful to my eyes.